# How to shutdown Windows 8 remotely without the Start button?

Tags: windows-8-preview

I'm using Windows 8 CP, the latest one.
No Start button, well, okay.
But I can't find the way to shutdown it through Remote Desktop Connection.
Anyone succeeded? Or do I have to use a command/shell script?

Comment: The same way as you would shut it down locally.

Answer (score 14, accepted):

To normally shut down:

```
Shutdown -s
```

For restarting:

```
Shutdown -r
```

Answer (score 24):

Press Alt+F4 on empty Desktop.

Answer (score 4):

I took the opportunity to kill two birds with one stone.

a) Create my own Shutdown Button (tile)

b) Learn how to create Windows 8 tiles on the desktop.

It was tricky, but satisfying.

http://www.computerperformance.co.uk/win8/windows8-shutdown-command.htm

Answer (score 1):

On a Mac using Cord instead of RDC, you can hit <kbd>Alt</kbd>+<kbd>Fn</kbd>+<kbd>F4</kbd> at the same time to bring up the shutdown/restart option window when on the desktop.